# python 3.6 aiohttp - сервер возвращающий файл

Tags: python-3.6, aiohttp

Помогите освоить aiohttp!
Не очень понял из документации, как сделать сервер, который будет на такие запросы возвращать нужный файл. Напишите, пожалуйста, пример. Я новичок, так что буду благодарен в двойне за пояснения.

```
import os
import aiofiles
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from asyncio import get_event_loop
from async_timeout import timeout as as_timeout


async def download_coroutine(session, url):
    with as_timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            filename = os.path.basename(url)
            async with aiofiles.open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
                while True:
                    chunk = await response.content.read(1024)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    await fd.write(chunk)
            return await response.release()


async def init(loop):
    async with ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        for file_name in file_names:
            url = "http://{}:{}/{}".format(ip_address, port, file_name)
            await download_coroutine(session, url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip_address = "localhost"
    port = 8080

    file_names = ["download.jpg, some.exe"]

    loop = get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
```

Comment: О чем вообще этот вопрос? При чем тут сервер?

Comment: Хочу сделать на aiohttp что-то типа хранилища файлов, типа из скрипта обращаться к серву, передавая имя файла и, если файл существует, возвращать поток, который клиент будет записывать. В будущем можно докрутить и отправку на сервер через скрипт.

Или так неправильно?
Спасибо за ответ.